# How to find the correlation coefficient of one piece of data in a set?

Tags: correlation

I have a set of two pieces of data with a 0.85 coefficient.  How can I calculate the coefficient for each individual set of data?  For example, one set is 0-200 (x) and the other one is 0-$500,000 (y).  How can I get a coefficient for one data point?

Answer (score 0):

Correlation is a statistical relationship between two variables in a set of data. You therefore cannot correlate a single point of data with another single point of data, or at least not in a meaningful way.

Comment: I have two sets of data.  I am trying to find how far off a single set is from the group.

Comment: This is not what you use correlation for. If you want to measure the distance of a single point from your distribution, you have to define a metric with which to quantify this distance. You could for example measure the Euclidean distance of a point to the center of your distribution. This generally works well for data with low dimensions and many points that are somewhat normal distributed. For higher dimensional or not as evenly distributed data, you will have to find a different solution.